# How to force the browser to use Application/Octet-stream header from a Spring Controller

Tags: java, html, spring

I have a page which displays links to files which are stored as BLOBs in the database. In multiple browsers one of the links is displaying csv information inline instead of downloading as a CSV file. A user would be able to right click and download, but how can I enforce a download as the default browser action, as the content type and content-disposition do not seem to be sufficient. I am on an older version (3.2.4) of the Spring Framework.

Edit: If I do not set the headers all links are displayed inline. 
Also, when the headers are set, there is an error reported in the Safari console for the links that download and are not displayed inline:

"Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted"

```
//front end code
<td><a id="downloadFile" href="<c:url value='/test/file/errors/${fileError.id}'/>" 
class=".icon-download"> 
<span class=".icon-download"></span>${fileError.filename}</a></td>

//Spring controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/file/errors/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void downloadFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
      HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputError file = commonService.get(InputError.class, id);
    try {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getFile());
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
     response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"");
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, I solved this by setting the headers before the IOUtils.copy.

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"");
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the **download** attribute introduce in html5 ?

```
<td><a id="downloadFile" href="<c:url value='/test/file/errors/${fileError.id}'/>" 
class=".icon-download" download="filename_here.txt"> 
<span class=".icon-download"></span>${fileError.filename}</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it did not work, the file is still displayed inline by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Benoit, if you can use HTML 5 the download option would work.

However, despite it being somewhat nit-picky, your current answer should work.  So in this case, have you tried using the appropriate casing for the MIME-type?

```
Content-Type="application/octet-stream"
```

Part of the value in using Spring's MediaType class is remove 'magic number' values like this from your code, and ensure odd behavior doesn't happen.

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried adding an html 5 doctype, the download attribute and also the spring mediatype constant, but still not working. I have also tested in chrome and the links work (with and without the suggested changes), but inline with IE or Safari.